# a multiple definition error in c++

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I have 2 files, grabURL.cpp and grabURL.hpp. When I compile the both with gcc it gives me multiple definitions errors.

grabURL.cpp

```
#include "grabURL.hpp"
size_t buffer(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) { 
            int numbytes = size*nmemb; 
            char lastchar = *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1); 
        *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = '\0'; 
            ret.append((char *)ptr); 
            ret.append(1,lastchar); 
        *((char *) ptr + numbytes - 1) = lastchar;
    return size*nmemb; 
 }
void grabURL(std::string url, std::string *theRet){
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, buffer);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
*theRet = ret;
}
```

grabURL.hpp:

```
#ifndef CURLURLGRAB_HPP
#define CURLURLGRAB_HPP
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
CURL * curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string ret;
size_t buffer(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream);
void grabURL(std::string url,std::string* theRet);

#endif
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I thought I did the ifndef thing correctly. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: What are the *exact* error messages?

Comment: g++  main.cpp grabURL.cpp -o test -lcurl
/tmp/cceVAPGI.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `curl'
/tmp/ccC6uR4k.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cceVAPGI.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `res'
/tmp/ccC6uR4k.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/tmp/cceVAPGI.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `ret'
/tmp/ccC6uR4k.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitions in your header file:

```
CURL * curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string ret;
```

get defined when you include the file from the cpp file, and pressumably some other translation unit (perhaps main.cpp?)

They don't look like something that should be in a header file, but if they do then you can declare them `extern` within the header file and move the actual definitions to the cpp file.

Comment: I put CURL * curl and CURLcode res in the .cpp file and no errors were generated. What exactly makes it not something you wouldn't put in a header file? I'm not defining any variables yet.

Comment: @user1042519: What do you mean? Those 3 are variable definitions. And one does not usually want any variable definition within a header file, because it triggers multiple definition errors.

Comment: So why is it that I can do things like that in classes and not on the .hpp file itself? Maybe I'm thinking it works exactly like classes.

Comment: @user1042519: Because member objects of a class aren't instantiated until an object of such class is instantiated. Unless they are static member objects, which are indeed variable definitions.